# webpack: export/import function with properties

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

I have a frontend library made by myself and I'm trying to use it in build process with webpack. The library was working with a direct loading in the browser through a  tag but I decided to move to a build process.
There are a set of functions which I'm using like classes through prototype paradigm (i know there is class construct in ES6, but i have to avoid complete rewrite of this library).

I have a "class" function (that is the constructor) called Widget which I export, but this function has also a "static method" get which is assigned directly to the function as a property.

```
//widget.js file content
export function Widget()
{
....
}
Widget.prototype=....
Widget.get=function()
{
....
}
```

In another module I simply import it through named import. Then, When I use Widget it is working perfectly but when I try to use the "static method" get it says that is undefined.

```
//main.js file content
import {Widget} from "./widget.js"
var w= new Widget();//---working! Widget is defined and i can use it
var a=Widget.get(...);//--- not working! Widget.get seems to have been not exported
```

I cannot understand why `.get` that is simply an attribute of a function is has not been exported (or imported).

Is there an explanation and of course a way to make i work?

PS: of course I don't want to use `Widget.prototype.get=function(){....}` because in this way `.get` method will become a "instance method" not a "class method".

Thanks

Comment: Do you use `sideEffects` property in your library's `package.json`?

Comment: No. My library has not been build as independent module. It is a simple js file with this set of functions. So I build it together with the app I'm using with.

Comment: Did you check the compiled output? The static function is removed?

Comment: No. It has not been removed. I can seet inside the app.js (under the eval part produced by webpack) the piece of code Widget.get= function(){...} ... I suppose it has something to do with the dynamic export of a ES6 module.